# How can I programatically record browser actions without using a plugin

Tags: javascript, browser

How can I programatically record a browser actions without using a plugin?

In Mozilla we record through a mozilla plugin (Selenium IDE) and can export to any language which selenium supports.

But I don't want to use a plugin but record the actions performed in a website through a code/set-up and also replay it if possible.

want to record the js actions using a javascript

Comment: May I know the reason for downvoting this question again please

Answer (score 0):

Why would the browser plugin not solve the purpose here ? Can you please elaborate as to where does it fall short for you ?

Proxy server to the best of my knowledge cannot do this sort of a thing because all it gets to know is a request to the web server by the browser for a page serve, and a response from the web server to the browser which goes via it. But in between these two, there could be user actions on the html elements which the proxy server would be agnostic about.